# Add fadeOut before fadeIn to the script used as filter based on classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using this script to filter elemets based on class. Currently it stops previous function and fade in new class, i need it to stop, fade out everything (it can be specific class, eg. .all) then fadein as it is now. I am not able to add thet fade out to the script.

Thanks for help.

Heres the script:

```
<script>
$('div.tags').delegate('input[type=radio]', 'change', update);
update();
function update() {
    var $lis = $('.results > div'),
        $checked = $('input:checked');
    if ($checked.length) {
        var selector = $checked.map(function () {
            return '.' + $(this).attr('rel');
        }).get().join('');

        $lis.hide().filter(selector).stop().fadeIn(1000, 'easeInCirc');

    } else {
        $lis.stop().fadeIn(1000, 'easeInCirc');
    }
}
</script>
```

Basically i need to fadeOut everything before it starts to fadein selector. Currently it is a sharp cut from 100% opacity to starting fadeing in selector, and i want to smoothly fade out current (or specific class) and after that fade in this one.

Answer (score 0):

Then you have to use the complete callback:

```
<script>
$('div.tags').delegate('input[type=radio]', 'change', update);
update();
function update() {
    var $lis = $('.results > div'),
        $checked = $('input:checked');
    if ($checked.length) {
        var selector = $checked.map(function () {
            return '.' + $(this).attr('rel');
        }).get().join('');

        $lis.fadeOut(200, function({
    $lis.filter(selector).stop().fadeIn(1000, 'easeInCirc')
});

    } else {
        $lis.stop().fadeIn(1000, 'easeInCirc');
    }
}
</script>
```